# Different paths for installing Python modules ok?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module

99% of time when I import modules in VS code, the folder "scripts" is used for storage.
Today, I tried to install the modules "secret" and "MSG", the modules are in "sites-packages" in "lib" in the python folder.

Do you know why and how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same version on VSCode for all these installs? Sometimes you need to specifically select the python version when in VS Code

Comment: Some packages put themselves in `site-packages`. You don't need to fix it, and I suspect it might not be a good idea to try.

Comment: How can i use the modules them ?

Comment: @SRP You can import them directly because the `site-packages` was in the `sys.path` by default.

Comment: It's working thx !